# Stopping sound from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, audio

I have played a sound in classA, and does anyone know how to stop it in classB?

I have read several posts already, most of them just mention about creating an instance (i.e. things like Class A *a in .h, and a =[[Class A alloc]init] in .m). This wont work for some reasons.

Here are some codes:
In classA.m

```
path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:[@"songName" ofType:@"mp3"];

av1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: path1] error:NULL];
[av1 play];
```

In classB.m,

a = [[classA alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

```
 [a.av1 stop];
```

Comment: The actual situation is that, an audio is played in class A, then another audio is played in classB, so I want to stop the audio in classA first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're doing here,

```
a = [[classA alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[a.av1 stop];
```

is wrong. You're creating a completely new object which is all probability isn't playing any music and sending a `stop` message to its player. If you want to stop the player in the other class, you must store an `assign`ed reference of the other class. If you wish to keep them independent, you can look at notifications. [`This`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) is a definitive guide from Apple. Basically, this will involve registering A as the observer to a notification and then when B is ready to play it will post the notification that it's about to play music. When A receives that notification should turn off its music.

So in the `init` of `A`, register yourself as an observer,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(turnOffMusic:) 
                                             name:@"BWillPlayMusicNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

and then when the B object is ready to play music, post the notification,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:@"BWillPlayMusicNotification"];
```

This will result in A's `turnOffMusic` being invoked which will pretty much do,

```
- (void)turnOffMusic:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.av1 stop];
}
```

Remember to stop listening to notifications when the object is deallocated,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

This approach allows you to keep both classes independent.

Comment: And just to add something, I think the 2nd part should be             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BWillPlayMusicNotification" object:nil];

Comment: @xcoder, This is one way of doing it, but your main problem is that you don't understand the fundamental concept on OOP. You need to understand the difference between classes and objects. Having a look at naming conventions wouldn't hurt you either. Example of a correctly named class: `ClassA` (notice the capital C), and a correctly named object: `objectA`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to stop the sound in class A?

Just do the same thing, but in class B.

Comment: The audio is played in classA, so simply calling [audioClassB stop] would not work...

Comment: this is exactly my question =] It does not work for some reasons

Comment: @xcoder, Then post some code to show us what you are doing and we'll see what we can do to fix it.